# What's wrong with this experiment to measure the one way speed of light?

Tags: speed-of-light, thought-experiment

It's pretty simple so there must be something obviously wrong with it but what is it?
Starter is an electric signal emitter that sends a pulse to the laser source and the detector, starting a counter in both, it is located at the exact halfway point between them.

So basically you send out the starter signal that starts a counter clock in both ends at the same time (or does it?) then you fire the laser. When you fire the laser the counter at the source stops. When the detector detects the laser the counter there stops too. Now you have the time it took for light to get from source to detector. What is the problem?

LaserSource-----------------------------Detector

```
            <----starter---->
```

Comment: "...starts a counter clock in both ends at the same time then you fire the laser. When you fire the laser the counter at the source stops." - Why bother having a counter at the laser source if it stops immediately?

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear enough, I shoot the laser after the counters are started at both ends.I need both counters to tick at least once to get a measurement.

Comment: How does the clock at the detector know when the laser has been fired?

Comment: It only knows to stop counting when the detector detects the light.

Comment: Right - when does it start counting?

Comment: When it receives the electric starter signal from the middle.

Comment: Of course, I'd misunderstood what you wrote. In that case, I can't see anything wrong with the principle of the experiment: just because it's simple doesn't mean it's wrong!

Comment: In principle it is good. The practcal problem is getting the time measurements accurate enough. Also getting the time delay between when the laser receives the signal and when it fires.

Comment: The electric signal sends a pulse, which is EM radiation, which propagates at the speed of light. The main problem with all these setups is clock synchronisation: moving the clock causes it to desynchronise, whilst sending any type of signal to sync the clocks ends up relying on the speed of light itself.

Comment: What if we exchange the electric signal to mechanical ones? Two rods pushed outward from the middle. Then the signal travels waves in the material at the speed of sound in the given material. Then we can leave the speed of light out of it, no?

Comment: @Saffer I'll add this to an answer

Comment: Why not just time a laser pulse as it propagates to a mirror and back (and measure the distance)? This would be about as accurate as your proposal, no?

Comment: @Gilbert that measures the two-way speed of light. The question is about the one-way speed of light.

Comment: @Eletie “One-way” speed of light? Is this some sort of time-reversal-asymmetric system?

Comment: @Gilbert https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_speed_of_light

Comment: @Eletie Fair enough! I totally missed the implicit context of this question.

Answer (score 3):

If I've understood yours setup correctly: the electric signal sends a pulse, which is EM radiation, which propagates at the speed of light. So you've already assumed the speed of light is *isotropic* in the setup.

The main problem with most of these proposed experiments is clock synchronisation: moving the clock causes it to desynchronise, whilst sending any type of signal (regardless whether it's EM or not) ends up relying on the the speed of light or some sort of clock [synchronisation convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_synchronisation). Think about Lorentz transformations & velocity when considering your other suggestion about using rods: remember that *all* speeds are affected, not just light.

This is covered in great detail in *Conventionality of synchronisation, gauge dependence and test theories of relativity*, Anderson et. al.
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0370157397000513.

Comment: I devised this same experiment, and was about to ask this same question, but found this in the search results. My question is: who says the synchronization pulse has to be radiation- or light-based? Why can't it be something material, like two marbles sent down two different pipes, or a person closing a switch with each of their hands?

Comment: @TheWreckersCompanion because the Universe is relativistic, so at the end of the day all methods of sending a signal will be related to $c$. (e.g., forces are mediated by massless particles that travel at the speed of light)